# How to convert less than twenty number in words - Converting numbers to words

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am writing my technique for converting numbers to words. This works perfectly fine as long as any number between 11-19 comes in the number (either at the end or somewhere in the number).

I have seen various implementations regarding the solution, but I wrote down the algorithm that works except for the scenario of the above-mentioned. I want to handle this mentioned scenario within this algorithm.

```
int i = 0, multiplier = 1, length = nums.Length -1;

string[] lessThanTwentyWords = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                                              "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve",
                                              "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen",
                                              "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"
                                            };
string[] tens = new string[] { "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" };

Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> posVsWordsMap = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>()
{
    [1] = new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("",lessThanTwentyWords),
    [10] = new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("", tens),
    [100] = new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("Hundred", lessThanTwentyWords),
    [1000] = new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("Thousand", lessThanTwentyWords),
    [10000] = new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("",tens),
    [100000].........................................................
    ...............
};

string completeText = "";
for(var i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
  var number = array[i];
  if(number !=0)
  {
    text = posVsWordsMap[multiplier].Value[number-1];
    var hundredsText = posVsWordsMap[multiplier].Key;
    multiplier *= 10;
    completeText += text + hundredsText;
  }
}
```

Explanation :

What I am doing :

Iterating from the backward of the integer/long approaching to the most significant position of the integer.

Upon each iteration, multiply with the corresponding position with the multiple of 10 which becomes the first 10, 100, and 1000 so on.

Then I am stuck processing the numbers like 11, 15-and 19 which can come wither at the end or the beginning or even in the middle somewhere.

CAn anybody help me how can I accommodate test case of 11-19?

Comment: Do you _want_ to do it yourself or would using "Humanizer" or something similar be an option?

Comment: didnt get regarding 'Humanizer'?

Comment: Your code has several undefined variables. Please make it compilable.

Comment: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer scroll down to "Numbers to words"

Comment: No of course not a humanizer at all. But I need to do it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

To turn numbers to English words has quite a few complications that your code does not handle. Those include:

- Support for "zero"
- Inserting spaces, hyphens, or the word "and", where appropriate
- Grouping by 3 (so that 101000 will not become one hundred thousand one thousand, but one hundred and one thousand).
- ...

But let's focus on the question about 11-19. The trick is to look at the next digit and check whether it is a one, and if so, to deal with that extra digit in the same iteration of your loop. But be aware that the position of this pair of digits is important. For instance, 14 becomes "fourteen", but 142 does not become "fourteen two". Pairing two such digits should only be done in one of three positions, so 14000 again has a suitable position of a pair to perform this merge.

A few other issues:

- `array.length` should be `array.Length` if `array` is an array
- `multiplier *= 10` should also happen when `number` is zero
- `completeText` should get the new words *prepended*, not *appended*.

Here is your code with these corrections:

```
string completeText = "";
int multiplier = 1;
// Fixed spelling of array.Length
for (var i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var number = array[i];
    // Detect when we have a case of "eleven" to "nineteen":
    if (i > 0 && (array.Length - i) % 3 == 1 && array[i - 1] == 1) {
        // Merge this iteration with the next: take two digits
        i--;
        number += array[i] * 10;
    }
    if (number != 0)
    {
        var text = posVsWordsMap[multiplier].Value[number - 1];
        var hundredsText = posVsWordsMap[multiplier].Key;
        // Prepend instead of append
        completeText = text + hundredsText + completeText; 
    }
    // Multiplier should ALWAYS be adapted
    multiplier *= number > 9 ? 100 : 10;
}
```

As stated above, this only deals with the issue you raised. There are quite a few other features you'll want to address, as listed at the top of this post.

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?